# error in compiling latex

Tags: compilation-error

what's the meaning of \ProvidesPackageRCS[v\pgfversion] $Header: /cvsroot/pgf/pgf/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex,v 1.25 2013/12/13 11:40:27 tantau Exp $.

I have updated both tex studio to 4.0.0. and MiKTeX console. still, it comes. What is the solution for it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: That does not look like an error message. Please post a minimal example that gives the error and post the exact error

Comment: Note that the editor of choice has nothing to do with larex errors, it only saves the code to disk and calls latex on it